# People in hazmat suits get turned into faceless zombies with lighting/electricity appearing inside their helmets

Tags: story-identification, horror

It's a black-and-white film.  There's a group of scientists/astronauts/technicians wearing hazmat/space suits. They're in some sort of lab or factory doing research or fixing something. They take turns looking into some hole. One after another, each person turns into a faceless zombie-like version of himself with electricity sparking inside their helmets like a plasma orb.

I remember watching this one many years ago. I did some research online and concluded that is not a Twilight Zone episode. I would like to know what movie/show this is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Episode of *The Outer Limits* entitled ["Production and Decay of Strange Particles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_and_Decay_of_Strange_Particles).

Researchers wearing hazmat suits perform experiments in nuclear physics. They inadvertently create a nuclear life form. It invades the hazmat suits, filling them with lightning and enslaving the researchers.

Episode is apparently loosely based on Edmond Hamilton's short story [*Transuranic*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63164).

Comment: out of curiosity, you knew this or had to search?

Comment: I actually saw that episode (in re-run) and had read the Edmond Hamilton story. Because I am getting up in years.

Comment: I envy how good memory you have, even in your years ;)